# Piezo not making sound

Tags: arduino-uno, piezo

I've used the piezo on other projects with no problem, but for some reason this project isn't working out so hot.

Here's a photo of my current set up.

[image: Uno layout]

Here's the basic code that I presumed would make a sound, but no such luck.

```c
void setup() {}

void loop() { 
  tone(12,260);
  delay(10);
}
```

Not sure where to begin debugging this...

Comment: I can't see any wires connecting to the Piezo.

Comment: @Majenko 2 and 6 on the breadboard connect to the piezo.

Comment: No they're not - they're on the wrong side of the board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Majenko pointed out, the wires are not connected to the piezo.  By moving the piezo to the correct rails on the other side of the board, the circuit would be completed and the piezo should work.

**Edit:** 
Building on Nick Gammon's comment, the rows of each side of a breadboard are not connected (to allow DIP packages).

Comment: To explain a bit more: for each number `abcde` are interconnected, and so are `fghij`, but those pairs are not connected.

Comment: And the *reason* for this is: You can plug a chip into the middle of the board, one set of legs is on one side, and you can plug your breadboard wires into them, and the other set of legs is on the *other* side. If the sides were connected together, the chip wouldn't work.

Comment: Ah! Perfect. That did the trick. Thanks so much!